# RxJS - split by partitions and emit with iterval

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

How can I achive something like the following using RxJS?

a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h

ab---cd---ef---gh

or

a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h

abc----def----gh

I have an array which I need to split by specified partitions and emit values with specified interval.

Comment: are this partitions size based? lets say, you want a list to be partitioned on groups of 3?

Comment: Yes, they are partinioned by size. I may need 2, 3, 4 and etc. (configurable value)

Answer (score 4):

Note you can't get 'ab--' from 'a-b-' because you must wait for 'b', so strictly the marble diagrams will be

```
a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-|
-(ab)---(cd)---(ef)---(gh|)

or

a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-|
--(abc)----(def)----(gh|)
```

```js
console.clear() 
const Observable = Rx.Observable

const timedEmitter = (observable, interval) => 
  Observable.zip(observable, Observable.timer(0, interval))
    .map(x => x[0])

const source = Observable.from(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])
const timedSource =  timedEmitter(source, 1000)

const interval = 5000
const size = 3
const output = timedEmitter(timedSource.bufferCount(size), interval)

//Display
const start = new Date()
output.timestamp()
  .map(x => { return {value: x.value, elapsed: x.timestamp - start} })
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

**Footnote**, changing `Observable.interval(interval)` to `Observable.timer(0, interval)` in timedEmitter to get first emit asap.

<s>**Footnote#2**, this is not quite right, because the `complete()` of source shorts the last interval.</s>
This was just an artifact of the chosen intervals.

---

Here's a custom operator version using `pipe()` from RxJs 5.5, ref [Build your own operators easily](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md#build-your-own-operators-easily)

```js
console.clear() 
const Observable = Rx.Observable

const timedEmitter = (observable, interval) => 
  Observable.zip(observable, Observable.timer(0, interval))
    .map(x => x[0])

const source = Observable.from(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])
const timedSource =  timedEmitter(source, 1000)

// Custom operator
const timedBufferedEmitter = (interval, bufferSize) => (observable) =>
  Observable.zip(observable.bufferCount(bufferSize), Observable.timer(0, interval))
    .map(x => x[0])

const interval = 5000
const size = 3
const output = timedSource.pipe(timedBufferedEmitter(interval, size))

//Display
const start = new Date()
output.timestamp()
  .map(x => { return {value: x.value, elapsed: x.timestamp - start} })
  .subscribe(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed!